# Find the fastest route depending on slope

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have two ways drawn on a map and I'm supposed to calculate which one is the fastest from start to finish. The assumption is that you run with a speed of 4 min/km on flat ground, each percent increase of average slope increase the time with 15 sec/km.

As indata I have an elevation raster and an orthophoto in  jpg-format with corresponding jgw-file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If you have Spatial Analyst, you can calculate a percent slope raster from the DEM.